# Prove that $2^{11}-1$ is a composite by using Femat's factorization method.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We need to find $x,\ y$ s.t. $$ x^2\equiv y^2\pmod n $$ where $n = 2^{11}-1$.

Note that $$ 2^{12} =2 n +2 $$

$$ 2^{14} = 2^3 n + 2^3 $$

Hence $$ 2^{12}\cdot 2^{14}\equiv 2\cdot 2^3\pmod n $$  and $$ n\mid (2^{13}-2^2)(2^{13} + 2^2) $$

Here $n\mid2^{13}-2^2$ and $n$ and $ 2^{13} + 2^2$ are relatively primes. So we need to find another one.

How can we prove that $n$ is a composite by using Fermat's factorization method ?

Comment: $2^{11}-1= 56^2-33^2=23\cdot 89$

Comment: If the question is only to know if $2^{11}-1$ is prime, then the answer is no : $2^{11}-1=2047=23 \times 89$.

Comment: You are running around in circles here, since you should know $2^{13}-2^2=2^2(2^{11}-1)=4n$ doesn't tell you anything about factors of $n$.

Comment: I prefer to note that if $q$ is a prime factor, then $q\equiv 1\pmod{11}$ and $q\equiv \pm1\pmod 8.$ This is equivalent to $q\equiv 1\pmod{88}$ or $q\equiv 23\pmod {88}.$ Given we only need to check prime divisors less than $50,$ this gives one prime to check.

Comment: I don't think that you want to use [Fermats factorization method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method#Basic_method). It is not related to Fermat's little theorem.

Answer (score 1):

$$45^2<n=2047^2=2^{11}-1 < 46^2
$$

If $f(x)= x^2-n,\ x\geq 46$, then we consider the number $t=t(x)$ of
ones place of $f(x)$ : Since only element in $A = \{ 1,\ 4,\ 9,\ 6,\
5\}$ can be in ones place of a square, then we must consider
$$t(x)\in B=\{4,\ 7,\ 2,\ 9,\ 8\}$$

Since $f(x)=y^2$, then $t(x)\in A$. Hence $$ x=46,\ 49,\ 51,\ 54,\
56,\ \cdots $$

$$ f(46)=69,\ f(49)=354=2\cdot 177,\ f(51)=554=2\cdot 277$$

$$ 29^2<f(54)=869 <900 ,\ f(56)=1089=33^2 $$

Answer (score 0):

$2^{11}-1\Longleftrightarrow 2^{22}-1\equiv 0\bmod 23$

$2^{11}-1\Longleftrightarrow 2^{66}-1 \equiv \bmod 67$

$2^{11}-1\Longleftrightarrow 2^{88}-1 \equiv \bmod 89$

$2^{11}-1\Longleftrightarrow 2^{198}-1 \equiv 
\bmod 199$

You have: $x^2-y^2\equiv \bmod (2^{11}-1)$

Or: $(x-y)(x+y)\equiv 0 \bmod(2^{11}-1)$

We check following cases:

Case 1):

$\begin {cases}x-y=23\\x+y=67\end {cases}$

which gives $x=45$ and $y=22$;

$45^2-22^2 \neq 2^{11}-1=2047$

Case 2):

$\begin {cases}x-y=23\\x+y=89\end {cases}$

which gives $x=56$ and $y=33$;

$56^2-33^2=2047=2^{11}-1$

which is correct.

Case 3):

$\begin {cases}x-y=67\\x+y=89\end {cases}$

which gives: $x=78$ and $y=11$;

$78^2-11^2==5963\neq 2^{11}-1$

Other cases also do not work.

So $n=2^{11}-1=23\times 89$ is composite.